# Joomla 4.0 Text sprintf

Tags: joomla-4.x, jtext

I know at some point `sprintf` was a method of the `JText` class, but it doesn't seem to work in Joomla 4.0. I tried the following, not working:

```
$str = Text::sprintf('JFIELD_COLOR_ADVANCED_INPUT_PLACEHOLDER', 'JFIELD_COLOR_ADVANCED_FORMAT_RGB');
```

Here's what I have and it works

```
$placeholder = sprintf(Text::_('JFIELD_COLOR_ADVANCED_INPUT_PLACEHOLDER'), Text::_('JFIELD_COLOR_ADVANCED_FORMAT_RGB'));
```

I need to know if there is a replacement for the deprecated `JText::sprintf()` method in Joomla 4.0, or is my method basically the way to do it now?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to translate the variables, you need to do it before passing them to `Text::sprintf()`:

```
Text::sprintf('JFIELD_COLOR_ADVANCED_INPUT_PLACEHOLDER', Text::_('JFIELD_COLOR_ADVANCED_FORMAT_RGB'));
```

This hasn't changed since J3 and `Joomla\CMS\Language\Text::sprintf()` is not deprecated in J4.